# Loop through the lists of lists using Python and append to dataframe

Tags: python

I am tried to loop through the lists of lists and **scrape** all the links and append them to dataframe as one table, but in vain.
Help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://money.rediff.com/companies/groups/A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
company_name = []
company_link = []
company_link_edit=[]

company_A_subpg1 = soup.find_all(class_='dataTable')

def convert(url):

  if not url.startswith('http://'):
    return 'http:' + url
  return url

data_df = pd.DataFrame()

for sub_tab in company_A_subpg1:
    for tab in sub_tab:

        sub_table_1 = tab.find_all('a', href=True)
        company_name = [name.text.strip() for name in sub_table_1]
        company_link = [name.get('href') for name in sub_table_1]
        company_link_edit=[convert(name) for name in company_link]

df=pd.DataFrame(
        {'Name':company_name,
         'Link':company_link_edit
         })
data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)


data_df.to_csv('results_3.csv')
```

Comment: what problem you are facing on running this code?

Comment: I have just edited my code , please look into it.

Comment: Also i get the following error: 'AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all''

Comment: @SahilDesai I am not able to collect all the links to pd.df

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: thank you for a quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://money.rediff.com/companies/groups/A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
company_name = []
company_link = []
company_link_edit=[]

company_A_subpg1 = soup.find_all(class_='dataTable')

def convert(url):

  if not url.startswith('http://'):
    return 'http:' + url
  return url

for sub_tab in company_A_subpg1:
  temp = sub_tab.find('tbody')
  all_rows = temp.find_all('tr')
  for val in all_rows:
    a_tag = val.find('a', href=True)
    company_name.append(a_tag.text.strip())
    company_link_edit.append(convert(a_tag.get('href')))


print(len(company_name), len(company_link_edit))

data_df = pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.DataFrame(
        {'Name':company_name,
         'Link':company_link_edit
         })
data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)

print(df.shape)

data_df.to_csv('results_3.csv')
```

You can check values inside csv file I fetched all the 200 names and link mentioned in the page.

Comment: Will be looking forward for your support in days to come @SahilDesai

Comment: @MathInquiry No problem. An upvote will be appreciated

Comment: Hi @SahilDesai , just curious to know what went wrong with my code and why the <datatable> failed to extract the links?

Comment: tab variable in your code was string which contained whole html data(We cannot iterate over html code).But, first we need to extract <a> tag from sub_tab than iterate over those values to get name and links.

Comment: Always use type() function to check what kind of data you are iterating through. It is helpful for me in debugging code.

Comment: glad to know that

Comment: Hi @SahilDesai, I have posted another question, please guide me to solution